# Test valid state transitions with scalacheck

Tags: scala, state-machine, scalacheck, property-based-testing

Suppose I have this class:

```
case class Receipt(id: Long, state: String) {
  def transitionTo(newState: String) = {
    if (!canTransitionTo(newState)) {
       throw new IllegalStateExcetion(s"cant transition from $state to $newState")
    }
    this.copy(state = newState)
  }
}
```

I'd like to test the logic in `canTransitionTo` (not included here for the sake of simplicity) with scalachecks Commands but I'm having a bit of trouble on how to begin. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are [some tutorials](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/testing-stateful-systems-scalacheck) how to test state machines with this framework but they test another property. Usually they create a `Command` for each valid transition and fire `scalacheck` to do any random combinations of them. The goal of such property is to verify that state machine behaves normally for any number of valid transitions.

This approach will not test `canTransitionTo` because it assumes all transitions are valid. Testing transitions between any pair of states will require to reimplement a notion of valid and invalid transitions in terms of `scalacheck`. This could be even more complex then original `canTransitionTo` function.

---

If one of transition sets is much smaller than other `scalacheck` can help to generate another one. For example if there are only handful of valid transitions and tenth of invalid then generators can help.

```
private val allStates: Gen[String] = Gen.oneOf("State1", "State2", "State3")

private val validTransitions: Set[(String, String)] = Set("State1" -> "State2", "State2" -> "State3", "State3" -> "State1")
private val validTransitionsGen: Gen[(String, String)] = Gen.oneOf(validTransitions.toSeq)

private val invalidTransition: Gen[(String, String)] = for {
  from <- allStates
  to <- allStates
  if !validTransitions.contains(from -> to) //this is reimplementaion of canTransitionTo
} yield from -> to

property("valid transitions") = forAll(validTransitionsGen) { transition =>
  Receipt(0, transition._1).canTransitionTo(transition._2)
}

property("invalid transitions") = forAll(invalidTransition) { transition =>
  !Receipt(0, transition._1).canTransitionTo(transition._2)
}
```